# Android. Панель со временем

Tags: android

Как в Android убирать верхнюю панельку со временем, с зарядкой и т.д.? Только не полностью убрать, а при открытии фотографии например, а после ее закрытия возвращать панельку.

Comment: Она называется панель уведомлений. Она же status bar.

Comment: а потом после запуска изменить все наоборот

Answer (score 3):

Надо установить флаги для окна:

1. Полный экран (строка состояния скрывается)

   ```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   ```
2. Ограниченный экран (с видимой строкой состояния)

   ```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

При открытии фотографии вызвайте такой код:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

После закрытия фотографии:

```
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Если вы используете Fragment для открытия фотографии, то лучше добавить флаг

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Этот флаг нужен для того чтобы разметка растягивалась после скрытия статус бара.

Подробнее [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status)